# can we use useSelector directly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, useselector

Normally it's been seen as using useSelector as follows

```
const count = useSelector(getCount);
addCount(count)
```

Is there any issue if we are using useSelector like given below?

```
addCount(useSelector(getCount))
```

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: As long as you're calling useSelector in the body of the component, and you don't need to use `count` anywhere else, go right ahead.

Comment: As long as that line (addCount) is not inside a function or conditionally called. You still have to follow the rules of hooks for it to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It still works! But best practice and clean code, you should write like first option!

```
const count = useSelector(getCount);
addCount(count)
```